# How to Solve Sql Command error invalid syntax near the keyword 'user'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect and fetch data from the table `dbo.user` but getting an error as Invalid syntax near the keyword 'dbo.user'
below is my code

```
private DataTable GetData()
{

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PoojaDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.user"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the issue in `sda.Fill(dt);` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is an SQL reserved word. Change the query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM dbo.[user]"
```

It is always preferred to decorate schema / table / column names with `[]` to avoid these errors.

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx):

> ODBC Reserved Keywords are reserved for use in
>   ODBC function calls. These words do not constrain the minimum SQL
>   grammar; however, to ensure compatibility with drivers that support
>   the core SQL grammar, applications should avoid using these keywords.